# Getting Instance of Object using win32 API

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, winapi, spy++

Hi I am trying to get a handle on a control in an external program. I can get the main form handle then the panel handle but am unable to determine what panel I am getting the handle of, as there is 4 panels that show using spy++

I know if I can select the panel by using the instance this would allow me to select the panel I want. I want to select TPanel3.

```
    Dim destination As IntPtr = FindWindow("TDeviceMainForm", "Gem")
    If destination Then MessageBox.Show("destination")
    Dim destControlpnl As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(destination, Nothing, "TPanel", Nothing)
    destControlpnl = FindWindowEx(destination, Nothing, "TPanel", Nothing)
    If destControlpnl Then MessageBox.Show("destControlpnl")
    Dim destControl As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(destControlpnl, Nothing, "TPanel", Nothing)
    If destControl Then MessageBox.Show("destControl")
```

Comment: It won't be `TPanel3`. It will be a control with class name `TPanel` and window name `Panel3`. I guess. You'll find it easily enough by asking for the control with that class name and window name.

Comment: The naming convention of the controls suggests that the VCL framework is being used. If that is true, it is common practice for VCL users to clear the `TPanel.Caption` property, in which case there would be no window name available to retrieve.  If "Panel3" it is not visible in Spy++, it will not be accessible via the Win32 API.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks you this has helped me a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all four panels are immediate children of the main window, you can use `FindWindowEx()` to enumerate them until you find the one you are interested in.  You do that be utilizing the `hwndChildAfter` parameter, eg:

```
Dim destination As IntPtr = FindWindow("TDeviceMainForm", "Gem")
Dim destControlpnl As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(destination, Nothing, "TPanel", Nothing)
destControlpnl = FindWindowEx(destination, destControlpnl, "TPanel", Nothing)
destControlpnl = FindWindowEx(destination, destControlpnl, "TPanel", Nothing)
```

This assumes the panels are ordered sequentially in the Z-Order of the main window's children.

That being said, the naming convention of the controls you mention suggests that the VCL framework is being used for that app's UI.  If that is true, it is common practice for VCL users to clear the `TPanel.Caption` property, in which case there would be no window name available to use during your searches.  If you do not see the string `"Panel3"` as the window name of the desired `TPanel` in Spy++, that window name will not be accessible via the Win32 API.  You would have to find some other criteria to validate which `TPanel` you really want, such as looking for a grandchild window that is specific to that one `TPanel`.

However, if you do see `"Panel3"` as the window name, then it is accessible via the Win32 API, and that will greatly simplify your search code down to a single `FindWindowEx()` call by using its `lpszWindow` parameter:

```
Dim destination As IntPtr = FindWindow("TDeviceMainForm", "Gem")
Dim destControlpnl As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(destination, Nothing, "TPanel", "Panel3")
```

Comment: Thank you this has cleared up a lot for me and also given me much more things to read up on :-)